# Getting Spring MVC model attributes in XsltView

Tags: java, xml, spring, xslt, spring-mvc

How do I access and handle model attributes (*model.setAttribute()*) in XsltView? Is there such possibility?

Comment: And what have you tried? where is your effort?

Answer (score 2):

There is even an example in [Spring Reference: Chapter 17.5 XSLT](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-xslt)

*I strongly recommend to read the reference before asking questions.*

Comment: In example stated that you need to include a DOMSource object into model and then work with it in XSLT. What I'm looking for is a method of handling objects, other than DOMSource, stored in model as I can in JSP (e.g. `object.property`).

Comment: @John Smith: read some documentation, try some stuff, read again, and if you then still stuck, write a question that exactly explain what you need and what you have tryed so far.

Comment: I already read what's written in documentation about XSLT view. And so far I wrote parsers for all of my objects to retrieve their properties and include this properties into DOMSource as stated in example from your link. Then I work with this XML in my XSLT. What I'm looking for is a method of handling objects from model as I can in JSP (e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="$object_from_model.its_property" />`). Do you understand?